# How to refresh the indexes in solr?

Tags: search, solr

i have changed one index in schema.xml and now want's to refresh all existing documents ..

How to do that ? i don't want to upload all documents again ...

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4):

if you changed the schema you HAVE TO reindex. After restarting Solr of course.

Updated:
If by 'adding one extra index' you mean adding one core, that core is empty so you have to add anything you need there.
If you change the way a field is analyzed, or add a field etc, you have to reindex again, your docs are not changed to reflect the change you made until you reindex

Comment: let's say i am adding one extra index ..

Still i have to upload all existing documents i have uploaded previously ... means it's kind of migration i have to do ....

and one more thing .. i can't do some refresh indexes means ... like analyze or something which will refresh indexes without uploading the document again .... ???

Answer (score 0):

How are you indexing the data? If you are getting the data from a database you can use a data-import handler and use a delta-import query. The delta-import will only update newly added fields. Check out this link for full documentation:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler